# Dragging UIView as subview of UITableView lags behind finger

Tags: performance, uitableview, drag, long-press

I have designed a custom subclass of UITableView.  At some point in its use, I need to add a UIView as a direct subview of UITableView, drag it within the table view using my finger, and then remove it from the table view.  I use a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to create a view in much a similar manner as the iOS Calendar app, drag it around the tableview by resetting its frame, and then remove it from the table view by adding it to a cell.

This works, but with one caveat.  When I move my finger too quickly, I "lose my grip" on the UIView, and it does not catchup to my finger unless I move my finger back within the frame of the view to "pick it up" again.

Since UITableView subclassed from UIScrollView, I tried setting the table view's delaysContentTouchs and canCancelContentTouches properties to NO, while setting the exclusiveTouch property of the UIView being dragged to YES.  Nothing has worked.

Ultimately, I want to be able to drag my UIView around inside the table view with just as much responsiveness as the built in iOS Calendar app.  Any thoughts?

P.S. I am relatively new to iOS development, so please forgive if there is some major oversight here.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! As it turns out, there was nothing inherently wrong with the setup (adding a subview to a UITableView and dragging).

After much digging, I discovered that I had been performing a hitTest every time the view was dragged to a new coordinate.  One could see how performing such an intensive operation every second could slow down processing enough on the device to cause this weird behavior.  When I changed it, everything worked perfectly.

Ultimately, the lesson to be learned was that my view controller subclass was too complex and therefore not easily readable.  There was too much digging necessary to uncover this issue.  I have since taken great pains to simplify my code - it has been incredibly rewarding.